# Responsive Emailer Image Position Issue(Center)

Tags: css, html, user-interface, html-email, responsive

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell:400,700|Oswald:400,700|Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         /* Linked Styles */
         body {
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important;
         display: block !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         background: #f1f2f3;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
         }
         a {
         color: #825162;
         text-decoration: none
         }
         p {
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important
         }
         img {
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
         }
         [style*="Cantarell"] {
         font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif !important;
         }
         [style*="Oswald"] {
         font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
         }
         [style*="RobotoCondensed"] {
         font-family: 'RobotoCondensed', sans-serif !important;
         }
         .text-c a,
         .text a {
         color: #6e3e4f !important;
         }
         .text-btn a {
         color: #ffffff !important;
         }
         /* Mobile styles */
         @@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
         table[class='mobile-shell'] {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         }
         table[class='center'] {
         margin: 0 auto !important;
         }
         td[class='td'] {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-5'] {
         height: 5px !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-10'] {
         height: 10px !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-15'] {
         height: 15px !important;
         }
         th[class='m-td'],
         td[class='m-td'],
         div[class='hide-for-mobile'],
         span[class='hide-for-mobile'] {
         display: none !important;
         width: 0 !important;
         height: 0 !important;
         font-size: 0 !important;
         line-height: 0 !important;
         min-height: 0 !important;
         }
         span[class='mobile-block'] {
         display: block !important;
         padding-top: 10px;
         }
         div[class='img-m-center'] {
         text-align: center !important;
         }
         div[class='fluid-img'] img,
         td[class='fluid-img'] img {
         width: 100% !important;
         max-width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
         }
         th[class='column'],
         th[class='column-top'],
         th[class='column-bottom'],
         th[class='column-dir'] {
         float: left !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         display: block !important;
         }
         td[class='content-spacing'] {
         width: 15px !important;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body class="body" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#f1f2f3; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f1f2f3">
         <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
               <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
                  <tr>
                     <td class="td" style="width:600px; min-width:600px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0"
                        <div class="fluid-img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left"><img src="#" border="0" width="600" height="12" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left">
                           <p valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #3f3f3f;font-family: Cantarell,Verdana,DejaVu Sans;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 400;line-height: 22px;text-align: left;margin:0px;">
                             <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <tr>
                                   <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="35"></td>
                                   <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- Hero Image --> 
                                      <div class="fluid-img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt;position: relative;text-align: center;left: 0;top: 0;">
                                         <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg" border="0" width="530" height="220" alt="" />
                                         <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/r1deesd55/a_com_logo_cllb.png" border="0" width="120" height="50" style="position: absolute; top: 50%;left: 40%;text-align: center;" alt=""/>
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="5" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="21" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END Hero Image --> <!-- TItle --> 
                                      <!-- <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="20" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         </div> -->
                                      <!-- END TItle --><!-- TItle --> 
                                      <div class="h2" style="color:#444444; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Oswald'; font-size:28px; line-height:41px; text-align:center; font-weight:normal"> Lorem Ipsum</div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="20" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END TItle --> <!-- Pre-header --> 
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="4" bgcolor="#825162"></td>
                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="15"></td>
                                            <td class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> <em>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</em> </td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="35" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END Pre-header --> 
                                      <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="40" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td align="center">
                                                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td class="text-btn" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; border-radius:2px; padding:8px 20px" bgcolor="#825162"> <a href="abcd.com" target="_blank" class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"><span class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">A B C D</span></a> </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="35" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#cccccc" class="border" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1" class="border" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="30" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="24" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f1f2f3">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="10"></td>
                                               <td>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <th class="column-dir" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; direction:ltr; Margin:0" dir="ltr" width="119">
                                                           </th>
                                                           <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0" width="15"></th>
                                                           <th class="column-dir" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; direction:ltr; Margin:0" dir="ltr">
                                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                 <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                       <td class="text2" style="color:#343434; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; text-align:left">
                                                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                                             <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                   <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                             </tbody>
                                                                          </table>
                                                                          <strong>Reference Number</strong>: Lorem Ipsum <br> <strong>Expiration Date</strong>: Lorem Ipsum <br> 
                                                                       </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                 </tbody>
                                                              </table>
                                                           </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                               </td>
                                               <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="10"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="28" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="35"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody> 
                             </table>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Amazon Logo Image is not centered in the Mailer. When I send this email in the mobile and open it in the gmail client. Image position is not centered then and in the tablet also. How can i center the Amazon logo image in the White box which is made for the logo.

Please help me out to center the image in the white box in both desktop and other mobile devices.

I have used testing email client putsmail.com and amazon logo is just for reference.

Comment: Your images are blocked from displaying to the public, so we can't really see what they are or how you want them to look.

At first glance in Chrome, it looks like you want a small image centered within a bigger image. This will never work in Outlook, Notes, Gmail, Yahoo to name a few. Email development is not front-end development. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.I belive this is what you are after. I recoded the header as VML + HTML. VML allows you to add background images in Outlook.You can use media queries to adjust the image spacing on mobile devices.

Note: You had spaces in your media queries that Gmail will not like, i have removed the extra spaces so it should work on Gmail as well now (unless Gmail sees anything else wrong with it).

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell:400,700|Oswald:400,700|Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         /* Linked Styles */
         body {
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important;
         display: block !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         background: #f1f2f3;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
         }
         a {
         color: #825162;
         text-decoration: none
         }
         p {
         padding: 0 !important;
         margin: 0 !important
         }
         img {
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
         }
         [style*="Cantarell"] {
         font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif !important;
         }
         [style*="Oswald"] {
         font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif !important;
         }
         [style*="RobotoCondensed"] {
         font-family: 'RobotoCondensed', sans-serif !important;
         }
         .text-c a,
         .text a {
         color: #6e3e4f !important;
         }
         .text-btn a {
         color: #ffffff !important;
         }
         /* Mobile styles */
         @@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px), only screen and (max-width:480px) {
         table[class='mobile-shell'] {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         }
         table[class='center'] {
         margin: 0 auto !important;
         }
         td[class='td'] {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-width: 100% !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-5'] {
         height: 5px !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-10'] {
         height: 10px !important;
         }
         div[class='mobile-br-15'] {
         height: 15px !important;
         }
         th[class='m-td'],
         td[class='m-td'],
         div[class='hide-for-mobile'],
         span[class='hide-for-mobile'] {
         display: none !important;
         width: 0 !important;
         height: 0 !important;
         font-size: 0 !important;
         line-height: 0 !important;
         min-height: 0 !important;
         }
         span[class='mobile-block'] {
         display: block !important;
         padding-top: 10px;
         }
         div[class='img-m-center'] {
         text-align: center !important;
         }
         div[class='fluid-img'] img,
         td[class='fluid-img'] img {
         width: 100% !important;
         max-width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
         }
         th[class='column'],
         th[class='column-top'],
         th[class='column-bottom'],
         th[class='column-dir'] {
         float: left !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         display: block !important;
         }
         td[class='content-spacing'] {
         width: 15px !important;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body class="body" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#f1f2f3; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f1f2f3">
         <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
               <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
                  <tr>
                     <td class="td" style="width:600px; min-width:600px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0">
                        <div class="fluid-img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left"><img src="#" border="0" width="600" height="12" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left">
                           <p valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #3f3f3f;font-family: Cantarell,Verdana,DejaVu Sans;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 400;line-height: 22px;text-align: left;margin:0px;">
                             <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <tr>
                                   <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="35"></td>
                                   <td>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- Hero Image --> 
                                      
                                      

                                     

                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      
                                      <div class="fluid-img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt;text-align: center;left: 0;top: 0;">
                                         <!--<img src="https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg" border="0" width="530" height="220" alt="" />-->
                                         
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td background="https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg" style="background: url('https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg'); background-image: url('https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg'); ">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:530px;height:220px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="https://s26.postimg.org/xb42o1n61/b2b-email-hero-container_1.jpg" color="#e9e9e9" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]--> 
<table width="120" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:130px 0px 75px 0px;"><img src="https://s26.postimg.org/r1deesd55/a_com_logo_cllb.png" border="0" width="120"  style="text-align: center;" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->


</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
                                         
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="5" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="21" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END Hero Image --> <!-- TItle --> 
                                      <!-- <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="20" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         </div> -->
                                      <!-- END TItle --><!-- TItle --> 
                                      <div class="h2" style="color:#444444; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Oswald'; font-size:28px; line-height:41px; text-align:center; font-weight:normal"> Lorem Ipsum</div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="20" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END TItle --> <!-- Pre-header --> 
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="4" bgcolor="#825162"></td>
                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="15"></td>
                                            <td class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> <em>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</em> </td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tr>
                                            <td height="35" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                         </tr>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <!-- END Pre-header --> 
                                      <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="text" style="color:#666666; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; text-align:left"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="40" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td align="center">
                                                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td class="text-btn" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; border-radius:2px; padding:8px 20px" bgcolor="#825162"> <a href="abcd.com" target="_blank" class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"><span class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none">A B C D</span></a> </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="35" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#cccccc" class="border" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1" class="border" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="30" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <div class="hide-for-mobile">
                                         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td height="24" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                               </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                      </div>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f1f2f3">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="10"></td>
                                               <td>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <th class="column-dir" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; direction:ltr; Margin:0" dir="ltr" width="119">
                                                           </th>
                                                           <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0" width="15"></th>
                                                           <th class="column-dir" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; direction:ltr; Margin:0" dir="ltr">
                                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                 <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                       <td class="text2" style="color:#343434; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif, 'Cantarell'; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; text-align:left">
                                                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                                             <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                   <td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                             </tbody>
                                                                          </table>
                                                                          <strong>Reference Number</strong>: Lorem Ipsum <br> <strong>Expiration Date</strong>: Lorem Ipsum <br> 
                                                                       </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                 </tbody>
                                                              </table>
                                                           </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                                     <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                           <td height="15" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                               </td>
                                               <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="10"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">
                                         <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td height="28" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                   </td>
                                   <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="35"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody> 
                             </table>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope the above code is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks a Lot !! It works like a charm . But can you tell what changes have you done? As i have changed the file due to stackoverflow text limit.

Comment: With the two images you tried to place them over each other using positioning. I removed the code and added VML code. Everything inside `<div class="fluid-img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt;text-align: center;left: 0;top: 0;">`. If this worked for you please select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks , yes it worked for me and I have marked as a correct answer.